# Sorting React elements using a react sorting library

Tags: reactjs, react-sortable-hoc

I want to use a React sorting library called, React Sortable HOC.  It seems like a great library, but I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to use it in my instance.

I set it up like one of the examples they provided:

```
const SortableItem = SortableElement(({ value }) => <li>{value}</li>);

const SortableList = SortableContainer(({ items }) => {
    return (
        <ul>
            {items.map((value, index) => (
                <SortableItem key={`item-${value}`} index={index} value={value} />
            ))}
        </ul>
    );
});

const onSortEnd = ({ oldIndex, newIndex }) => {
    this.setState(({ items }) => ({
        items: arrayMove(items, oldIndex, newIndex),
    }));
};
```

In the example, they map it from state like this:

```
return (
  <SortableContainer onSortEnd={this.onSortEnd}>
    {items.map((value, index) => (
      <SortableItem key={`item-${value}`} index={index} value={value} />
    ))}
  </SortableContainer>
);
```

But in my case, I am using 'map' to go through my state item(starships) and generating my data like this:

```
return (
   <div>
      {starships.map((starShip) => (
                <Ship starShip={starShip} />
      ))}
   </div>
);
```

Where Ship is this element:

```
const Ship = ({ ship: { ShipId, ShipName } }) => (
    <tr key={ShipId}>
        <td>{ShipNameName}</td>
    </tr>
);
```

I can't figure out how I'd use this library with the way I have my application set up.

Is there anyone who has used it like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can use it:

```js
const { SortableContainer, SortableElement } = SortableHOC;
const arrayMoveMutate = (array, from, to) => {
  array.splice(
    to < 0 ? array.length + to : to,
    0,
    array.splice(from, 1)[0]
  );
};

const arrayMove = (array, from, to) => {
  array = array.slice();
  arrayMoveMutate(array, from, to);
  return array;
};
function App() {
  const [ships, setShips] = React.useState([
    { ShipName: 'ship a', ShipId: 1 },
    { ShipName: 'ship b', ShipId: 2 },
    { ShipName: 'ship c', ShipId: 3 },
  ]);
  const onSortEnd = React.useCallback(
    ({ oldIndex, newIndex }) => {
      setShips(ships =>
        arrayMove(ships, oldIndex, newIndex)
      );
    },
    []
  );

  return (
    <SortableList items={ships} onSortEnd={onSortEnd} />
  );
}
const SortableList = SortableContainer(({ items }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((ship, index) => (
        <Ship
          key={ship.ShipId}
          index={index}
          value={ship}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
});

const Ship = SortableElement(
  ({ value }) => <li>{value.ShipName}</li>
);
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-sortable-hoc/0.9.0/react-sortable-hoc.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for the code examples!  Are the arrayMove functions you have the same as the ones in the array-move library that you can install via npm or are they custom?  thank you

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell They are [exactly the same](https://github.com/sindresorhus/array-move/blob/master/index.js). Not sure if it's a good idea to create a dependency to something that's only a couple of lines of code, feels like using leftPad

Comment: thanks! I had to modify it slightly on my end, but it works!